# UIButton disable click sound

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, uibutton, click

I use custom buttons for UINavigationBar. And the sound of clicking is played 0-2 times.

As I understand the simpliest way to solve this issue is to disable the sound of clicking for each button? So help me please

Comment: how did you add the sound to the UIButton????

Comment: I have found out that this problem is caused by UIDatePicker not by UIButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play sound by code reference [Click here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-button-sound.html)

Yes you can after disable button sound just set its tag to 111, And after action method just check

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{

 if(sender.tag == 111){
return;
}

//here is logic for sound play
```

}

Comment: i want to disable or replace this sound